# How to lerp movement of UI gameobjects in LayoutGroup?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I want to smoothly interpolate UI gameobject positions, instead of the default snapping that are handled by Unity's `LayoutGroup` class (specifically the `HorizontalLayoutGroup`). **The problem is that I don't know what method or property to access or override that the `LayoutGroup` class uses to move the UI objects after the layout calculations are done.**

---

I have been searching all over **`UnityEngine.UI`** and in their Bitbucket repository. If all fails I will have to create my own layout class, losing all of Unity's robust layout features.

Link to Bitbucket repo : https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0155c39e05ca/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/?at=5.2

---

I just need to find out what function or property in the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace can be used to override Unity's **LayoutGroup** child positioning so that it can be replaced a lerp or a tween.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask for direct answer, here is the method from `LayoutGroup` class:

```
 protected void SetChildAlongAxis(RectTransform rect, int axis, float pos, float size)
    {
        if (rect == null)
            return;

        m_Tracker.Add(this, rect,
            DrivenTransformProperties.Anchors |
            DrivenTransformProperties.AnchoredPosition |
            DrivenTransformProperties.SizeDelta);

        rect.SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(axis == 0 ? RectTransform.Edge.Left : RectTransform.Edge.Top, pos, size);
    }
```

which is being called from `HorizontalOrVerticalLayoutGroup` in method:

```
protected void SetChildrenAlongAxis(int axis, bool isVertical)
```

**BUT**

I would advise you not to play with this code as this is base class for all the layouts (Grid, Horizontal and Vertical). And changing behaviour would effect all derived layouts.

You can either **Create your own Layout Group**

or

**Work around the problem :**

1. Add empty child element of desired size and let the layout position it (this is container for your actual element).
2. Create a sub child of element you created in step 1(this is your actual element which is now controllable so you can position it, tween it etc).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. The sub child method is a brilliant idea that I haven't thought of! I'll post an update on completion with my result.

Comment: Yes, definitely use a "wrapper" as Umair explains!!